# How can i spawn a multiple instances of a container using kubernetes?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, multiple-instances

I have a container(Service C) which is listening to certain user event and based on the input it needs to spawn one or more instance of an another container(Service X).

Answer (score 1):

From your use case description, it looks like deployment is what you are looking for https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/ . By using deployments you can dynamically scale the number of instances of the pod.